# Hox fix GRUB bootloader on HP Probook 450 G4

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bootloader

I have HP Probook 450 G4 laptop, Windows 10 is only installed.But I need to dual boot or install any Linux distro.
When I try to dual boot with Ubuntu or install any Linux distro as single os,It failed.
Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] and describe what failed. And for dual-boot you can follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi . Ubuntu only should be much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)